# Paradox? law of large numbers vs option theory

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, finance, gambling

Flip a fair coin: if you get heads you win $120$, if you get tails you get $0$.
How much would you pay to play this game? $60$ right ?

Now let's consider the following situation:
You have an asset S that has value $S_0= 100$ at $t=0$. At time $t=1$, $S$ changes value to $S_1=200$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ or $S_1=40$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

How much would you pay for an option that pays $max(S_1-80, 0)$? If you work out the math, you will find that the options value is $45$.

But if you take a step back, this situation is identical to the first one (flipping the coin), there is a $50-50$ chance of winning $120$ or $0$.

So how much should someone pay to play any of these two games, $45$ or $60$?
According to option theory, if you pay $50$ you will lose money but that not really the case, especially if we repeat this game a big number of times.  How to reconcile these two situations? does it really make sense to price options the way we do in practice?

If the price is $50$, it seems that everyone is happy, the option dealer who can sell an option worth $45$ at $50$ and make $5$ as a profit and the gambler who on average is winning an extra $10$ per game. How can this be?

Comment: What is a "call option of strike $80$ with maturity $T=1$"? And what is the "second situation"? Probabilities and expected values often depend on how exactly the choices are made, so you better spell it out.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Is the current version better?

Answer (score 3):

In a perfect financial market, arbitrage opportunities should not be possible:

There must not exist a trading strategy $\phi=(\phi_{0},\phi_{1})$ investing money into the bank account and the stock such that

1. $\phi_{0}+100\phi_{1}=0$ ("initial value of $0$")
2. $\phi_{0}+P_{1}\phi_{1}\ge 0$ ("never lose in $t=1$")
3. $\phi_{0}+P_{1}\phi_{1}> 0$ with probability $>0$

because that would imply that we have can make a riskless profit - which does not make much sense mathematically.

These conditions are satisfied if and only if there is a risk-neutral probability measure (also called martingale measure) $Q$ under which the (discounted, which is irrelevant here) stock prices are all martingales. We then have to price derivatives **under Q** - otherwise again, there is arbitrage.

Here, $Q$ would be given by $Q(P_{1}=200)=0.375$ and thus the value of the option is $$V(0)=E_{Q}[(P_{1}-80)^{+}]=0.375\cdot 120=45$$

Now why is $P$ suddenly irrelevant for pricing? That is because the present day value of the stock already includes all information we need for pricing, and all individual risk preferences of the market participants.

The stock simply wouldn't valuate at $P_{0}=100$ if everyone would be prepared to buy it and risk losing $60$ units with a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$. It would instead immediately go up as a consequence of smart traders setting up arbitrage pottfolios.

For more details, see

https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/103/how-does-the-risk-neutral-pricing-framework-work

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am familiar with option pricing, that's how I got the value 45, but I'm still confused. It is still a paradox for me and I can't reconcile the two scenarios. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: What exactly is confusing you? The fact that we don't care about $P$?

Comment: It's mostly the fact that if we treat this as a game that could be played many times, the reasonable answer to price the game (either the coin flip or the option) is 60 but option pricing tells us that the "correct" price is 45.   Mostly the part that we don't care about the law of large numbers.

Also this part: "If the price is 50, it seems that everyone is happy, the option dealer who can sell an option worth 45 at 50 and make 5 as a profit and the gambler who on average is winning an extra 10 per game. How can this be?".

Comment: Everything is in the current price! Assume everyone would be willing to buy the option at $60$. Then immediately, traders would set up arbitrage portfolios. These portfolios involve buying the stock. Thus, the stock would go up way above $P_{0}=100$. But that has not happened! Our assumption must have been wrong: People are not willing to pay $60$ for the option.

Comment: Maybe one last point: The fair price of your fair-coin-martingale is **not** 60. It only is for someone with infinite wealth. Everyone else has the danger of going broke before LLN kicks in. This can be modeled by stopping times (see also Gambler's Ruin Problem)

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by MF14 is very good but maybe I can add something.

Consider a world in which the coin lottery, the stock and the option exist. Assume that the agents are risk neutral in the sense that they are indifferent between earning $60$ and playing a game with expected value $60$. Also, the risk-free rate is $0$. Then, under no arbitrage conditions:

- The lotery price will be $L_0=E[L_1]=60$
- The stock price will be $S_0= E[S_1]=120$
- The call option price will be $C_0=E_Q[S_1-80|S_1>80]=120 \cdot Q(S_1=200)=60$

Here the physical (real world) probability measure $P$ coincides with the risk-neutral probability measure $Q$.

Consider now a world in which the coin lottery, the stock and the option exist, but now the stock price is $S_0=100$. This implies that agents are risk averse (concave utility functions) as they are pricing the stock below its expected return. The risk-neutral probability measure implied by $S_0=100$ is such that $Q(S_1=200)=0.375$. Then we have:

- The stock price is $S_0=E_Q[S_1]$=100
- The option price is $C_0=E_Q[S_1-80|S_1>80]=120 \cdot Q(S_1=200)=45$
- The lotery price should be $L_0=45$ as it is equivalent to the option.

Essentially, when you write that the lotery price is $L_0=60$ and the stock price is $S_0=100$ you are defining implicitly two different preference profiles for the agents (and two different risk-neutral probability measures). These prices cannot exist in the same world.

Finally, as you noted, in the risk-averse world we can make profit on average if we buy any of the assets at the prices given. That is just the risk premium.